# CParserError while read csv file from wiki

Tags: python, pandas

From [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_college_towns#College_towns_in_the_United_States) on college towns is a list of university towns in the United States which has been copy and pasted into the file `university_towns.txt`.

I use `pandas.read_csv('university_towns.txt')` to read the file, but get the `CParserError` message.

I also try to set `error_bad_lines=False`, but it cause some data missing.

```
CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 8,saw 3
```

Comment: Could you please share how you are reading the file? By default pandas will use "," as a separator. So make sur the lines doesn't contain commas ",".

Comment: It seems like you have varying amounts of sepatators in the `university_towns.txt`. We need an extract of this file to percisely specify the error, but its likely, that your copy paste did not work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what changes you introduce to the list after you paste it to `university_towns.txt`. However, a quick look into the list shows that many of the universities names contain commas `,`. That's what causing `pandas.read_csv` to fail

```
Leeds (Leeds College of Art, Leeds College of Music, Northern School of Contemporary Dance, Leeds Metropolitan University, Leeds Trinity University, University of Leeds)
```

That's becasue, as explained in `pandas.read_csv` [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), comma is used `","` as the default separator `sep=","`. A quick fix is to change the separator as follows:

```
pandas.read_csv('university_towns.txt', sep="|")
```